# How detect ZipException with Objective-Zip?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objectivezip

I use Objective-Zip from github - https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip
If zip file broken i have this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'ZipException', reason: 'Can't open
```

And app crash after that.
How to get the error but the program did not fall?

Comment: catch the exception?

Comment: I need to not crash the application if file is broken, and show alertview that file is broken

Comment: Well, you have access to the source.  Modify it to handle the errors the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply catch the exception:

```
@try {
    // Zip code here
}
@catch (ZipException *exception) {
    // Error happened, do whatever you need
}
```